# Extjs 4 : Changing wallpaper from an iframe in the web desktop example

Tags: extjs, wallpaper

I begin with Extjs.
I'm facing a problem in **Extjs 4** with the **web desktop example**.
I'm using a window to display a php page inside an **iframe**.
In that page I'm using a javascript function to load a new src :

```
top.Ext.getDom('iframe-win').src = 'my-page.html';
```

This works great but now I'd like to modify the wallpaper at the same time with :

```
top.Ext.getBody().setStyle('background-image', 'url(./wallpapers/desk.jpg);');
```

But it fails in some way. My body got the new wallpaper but I don't target the right container.
What is the method to call in order to target this container ?

Comment: How does it fail? Does the wallpaper jpeg load, but not display or is the style not being set?

Comment: The wallpaper is loaded but not displayed because of getBody(). Is there somekind of getDesktop() to target the wallpaper div container ?